# how to pass an 2D array from code behind to JavaScript with web method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, code-behind, webmethod

I use web method, so I can pass string from code behind to JavaScript function.
but now in code behind I have 2D array and don't know how to pass it.

1- array in code behind is the same in JavaScript?
2- do I need to convert it and send or do I need to make a string and then send?
3- is it possible to send and read array directly without any changes?

what is best and quickest way?

Comment: Did you try: new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(your_array) ??

Comment: is it in code behind? i have a 2d array and need to send to javascript and there with array.

Comment: Yes, your method would: return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(toReturn); assuming toReturn is your array

Comment: it doesn't work i work vs2010

Comment: Did you reference using System.Web.Script.Serialization ? Because VS has nothing to do with it - its .Net Web assembly.

Comment: Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization//////Dim returnKey(,) As String = {{"", ""}}///////returnKey = {{"ant", "aunt"}, {"Sam", "Samantha"}, {"clozapine", "quetiapine"}}/////Return JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(returnKey)

Comment: This is usually how would you serialize your stuff for json to transfer. Sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: i serialize it, but now i can't deserialize in javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing array of strings to webmethod with variable number of arguments using jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971393/passing-array-of-strings-to-webmethod-with-variable-number-of-arguments-using-jq)