# Not Building jQuery ajax data correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following js code in my aspx page:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Reporting/landing.aspx/UpdateUserReportingSettings',
                        data: "{ 'reportingSettings' :" + columns.join() + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            window.top.location.href = "landing.aspx";
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert('Error Message' + thrownError);
                            alert('error' + xhr.responseText);
                       }
                    });
```

The columns are built up above this as so:

```
                    $('#currentColumnsList').each(function () {
                        // this is inner scope, in reference to the .phrase element
                        var column = '';
                        $(this).find('li').each(function () {
                            // cache jquery var
                            var current = $(this);
                            // check if our current li has children (sub elements)
                            // if it does, skip it
                            // ps, you can work with this by seeing if the first child
                            // is a UL with blank inside and odd your custom BLANK text
                            if (current.children().size() > 0) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            // add current text to our current phrase
                            column += (current.text() + ',');
                        });
                        // now that our current phrase is completely build we add it to our outer array
                        columns.push(column);
                    });
```

I then have a Web Method on code behind page as below:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void UpdateUserReportingSettings(string reportingSettings)
    {
        string columns = reportingSettings;

        //more code
    }
```

If I change the data line as below I can hit a breakpoint in the webmethod and the reportingSettings string will be test as expected:

```
data: "{ 'reportingSettings' : 'test' }",
```

If I alert columns.join() - I get the comma separated values something line columnA, columnB etc - what is the best way to get this passed acorss to the Code Behind WebMethod in the reportingSettings string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing ' symbol before columns.join(). It should be:

```
data: "{ 'reportingSettings' : '" + columns.join() + "'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way depends on your personal flavor I guess. But first of all I would try to add a single quote before the closing double quote

```
data: "{ 'reportingSettings' : '" + columns.join() + "'}"
```

instead of

```
data: "{ 'reportingSettings' : " + columns.join() + "'}"
```

Alternatively you could pass the parameters as an array. Something like

```
data: "{ 'reportingSettings' : {'ColumnA','ColumnB'}}"
```

And capture them with an array input parameter on your method like

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateUserReportingSettings(string[] reportingSettings)
```

An example can be found here : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971393/passing-array-of-strings-to-webmethod-with-variable-number-of-arguments-using-jq)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your js is that you've added the following line

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

The contentType in `$.ajax` is that the data that you send it to the server is of type `"application/json"`. But you're not sending the json data to the server. So, `$.ajax` is not able to hit the web method's breakpoint.

To convert your data to JSON, you've to explicitly make your data of json type.

```
var data = { reportingSettings: "" };

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Reporting/landing.aspx/UpdateUserReportingSettings',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            window.top.location.href = "landing.aspx";
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error Message' + thrownError);
            alert('error' + xhr.responseText);
       }
    });
```

Give it a try.

Hope this helps.